# Correlate a single time series with a large number of time series

Tags: python, performance, numpy, correlation

I have a large number (`M`) of time series, each with `N` time points, stored in an `MxN` matrix. Then I also have a separate time series with `N` time points that I would like to correlate with all the time series in the matrix.

An easy solution is to go through the matrix row by row and run `numpy.corrcoef`. However, I was wondering if there is a faster or more concise way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use this `correlation` formula :

[image]

You can implement this for `X` as the `M x N` array and `Y` as the other separate time series array of `N` elements to be `correlated` with `X`. So, assuming `X` and  `Y` as `A` and `B` respectively, a vectorized implementation would look something like this -

```
import numpy as np

# Rowwise mean of input arrays & subtract from input arrays themeselves
A_mA = A - A.mean(1)[:,None]
B_mB = B - B.mean()

# Sum of squares across rows
ssA = (A_mA**2).sum(1)
ssB = (B_mB**2).sum()

# Finally get corr coeff
out = np.dot(A_mA,B_mB.T).ravel()/np.sqrt(ssA*ssB)
# OR out = np.einsum('ij,j->i',A_mA,B_mB)/np.sqrt(ssA*ssB)
```

Verify results -

```
In [115]: A
Out[115]: 
array([[ 0.1001229 ,  0.77201334,  0.19108671,  0.83574124],
       [ 0.23873773,  0.14254842,  0.1878178 ,  0.32542199],
       [ 0.62674274,  0.42252403,  0.52145288,  0.75656695],
       [ 0.24917321,  0.73416177,  0.40779406,  0.58225605],
       [ 0.91376553,  0.37977182,  0.38417424,  0.16035635]])

In [116]: B
Out[116]: array([ 0.18675642,  0.3073746 ,  0.32381341,  0.01424491])

In [117]: out
Out[117]: array([-0.39788555, -0.95916359, -0.93824771,  0.02198139,  0.23052277])

In [118]: np.corrcoef(A[0],B), np.corrcoef(A[1],B), np.corrcoef(A[2],B)
Out[118]: 
(array([[ 1.        , -0.39788555],
       [-0.39788555,  1.        ]]),
 array([[ 1.        , -0.95916359],
       [-0.95916359,  1.        ]]),
 array([[ 1.        , -0.93824771],
       [-0.93824771,  1.        ]]))
```