# Correlation table

Tags: python, numpy, iteration, correlation

Suppose that you have hundreds of numpy arrays and you want to calculate correlation between each of them. I calculated it with the help of nested for loops. But, execution took huge time(20 minutes!). One way to make this calculation more efficient is to calculate one half of the correlation table diagonal, copy it to other half and make diagonal line equal to 1. What I mean is that, correlation(x,y)=correlation(y,x) and correlation(x,x) is always equal to 1. However, with these corrections, code will also take much time(approx 7-8 minutes). Any other suggestions?

```
My code
for x in data_set:
    for y in data_set:
        correlation = np.corrcoef(x,y)[1][0]
```

Comment: Have you considered using [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) since this is a fairly parallel problem?

Comment: No, I don't know anything about that package. Can you write a faster solution to this problem with help of multiprocessing?

Comment: Can you explain what is dataset, possibly providing a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Dataset is python dictionary in which, keys are names and values are pandas Dataframe which holds numerical data. Also, note that, dictionary is saved into pickle and each time, I load that data from pickle.

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30995062/correlate-a-single-time-series-with-a-large-number-of-time-series

Answer (score 1):

I am quite sure you can achieve must faster results by creating a 2-D array and calculating its correlation matrix (as opposed to calculate pair wise correlations one by one).

From numpy's corrcoef documentation the input can be:
" 1-D or 2-D array containing multiple variables and observations. Each row of m represents a variable, and each column a single observation of all those variables."
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html

Comment: Good idea! I will think about it.